# How to install 2 SSL certificates on a single Azure VM

Tags: azure

I have an Azure VM. I have hosted two applications with different domains. Both domains have an independent SSL certificate. Now I cant install two SSL certificates.

Is it possible to install 2 SSL certificates on the same Azure VM?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  it is possible to install multiple  certificates to windows Virtual machine running IIS.

Assuming the VM you are referring to runs Windows OS running IIS

**Step 1: Export all your certificates to .pfx file with Passwords (make sure to include the private key in the exported file)**

**Step 2: Copy the .pfx files to the target VM remotely.**

**Step 3: Open IIS -> Server Certificates -> Import wizard to install the certificates on the VM**

For more reference use this [link](https://clemmblog.azurewebsites.net/hosting-multiple-ssl-sites-in-azure-vms/)

And another way  create key vault and store certificate  in key vault and add certificate to vm
try these steps

**1)Create an Azure Key Vault.**

**2)Generate or upload a certificate to the Key Vault.**

**3)Create a VM and install the IIS web server.**

**4)Add the certificate to VM from key vault**

**5)Inject the certificate into the VM and configure IIS**

For more  reference use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server)